# python word counter w/ sorted frequency

Tags: python, counter, frequency

I'm trying to read a text file and then printing out all the words with the most frequent words on the top, decreasing as it goes down the list. I have Python 3.3.2.

```
def wordCounter(thing):
# Open a file
    file = open(thing, "r+")
    newWords={}
    for words in file.read().split():
        if words not in newWords:
            newWords[words] = 1
        else:
            newWords[words] += 1

    for k,v in frequency.items():
        print (k, v)
    file.close()
```

Now, it does print out everything the /way/ I want it, but there are some words that are used more than others that are lower down on the list. I've tried using newWords.sort(), but it says:

```
"AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort'"
```

So I'm at a loss of what to do, because my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have a `sort()`, but you can pass them to `sorted()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints the most used words first:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for k, v in sorted(frequency.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print(k, v)
```

The `key` is a function that is used for sorting. In our case `itemgetter` retrievs the value, i.e. the frequency as sort criterion.

Alternative without an import:

```
for k, v in sorted(frequency.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: You don't need any imports for something like this. And maybe an explanation?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 `itemgetter` is a bit nicer than  `lambda`. I think it is worth an import. I was still writing some explanation.

Comment: You don't need a `lambda` either.

Comment: I didn't use the export one, and I changed frequency to newWords (because the frequency was from trying to use the sort that didn't work) and it worked fine for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel a `collections.Counter` will do the counting and the ordering with `.most_common` which will give you the most to least common words in that order:

```
from collections import Counter
def wordCounter(thing):
   with open(thing) as f:
       cn = Counter(w for line in f for w in line.split())
       return cn.most_common()
```

You also don't need to read the whole file into memory, you can iterate line by line and split each line. You also have to consider punctuation which you can strip it off with `str.strip`:

```
def wordCounter(thing):
    from string import punctuation
    with open(thing) as f:
        cn = Counter(w.strip(punctuation) for line in f for w in line.split())
        return cn.most_common()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('file_name.txt') as f:
    c=Counter(f.read().split())
    print c.most_common()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries don't have a `sort()` method. However, you can pass a dictionary to the built-in function `sorted()` and it will produce a `list` of the dictionary's keys. Use a sorting key with a function that returns a dictionary key's value, which is the `get()` method.

```
for key in sorted(newWords, key=newWords.get):
    print(key, newWords[key])
```

Also, it looks like you've been doing some refactoring, as `frequency` isn't defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort without any imports:

```
word_count = sorted(new_words.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Note: Using a regular expression to print out all the words is a better approach:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

word_count = defaultdict(int)
pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*")
file = open("file.txt", 'r')
for line in file:
   for word in pattern.findall(line):
                word_count[word] += 1
```